# Concatenate strings in powerplatform using local variable

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

I have a workflow which retrieves some attachments from Microsoft Forms and add a work item to Azure Devops

I'm in a step where I have to add a table with two columns (Name and Url) like:

[image]

In `Url` column, I want to add hyperlink instead of text like:
`<a href='....'>Click here</a>`

I tried to add with `concat` expression like:

```
concat("<a href='", ..., "'>", "Click here", "</a>)
                     ^ here I don't know how to pass the link argument
```

How to pass `link` argument in `concat` epxression ?

Or what other approach should use if want to add hyperlink in column ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments in string like we do in `print` function elsewhere.

However you can use `replace` method to put your link inside the string. Just make sure to keep you text placeholder to be odd enough to not run into unwanted situation.

`replace("<a href='Placeholder_Text'>", "Click here", "</a>", 'Placeholder_Text', <Your dynamic URL will go here>)`

For further info, check the [Power Automate documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can add URL link with `concat`. In expression you just refer to link of the Body.

**Create HTML tag**

```
concat('<a href="', body()?['{Link}'], '">Short Name for link</a>')
```

The tricky part here is not  the `concat` function, but the fact that the HTML link will be stored as **plain text.**

You are working with HTML table and it will not allow you to add another HTML tags inside, as it could break the table.
So Power Automate will replace `<` with `&lt;` || `>` with `&gt;` || `"` with `&quot;` .

**Convert Plain text back to HTML**

So If you are looking for using this table somewhere (in the email) you can replace those characters back and it will be working as HTML.

Use nested `replace` expression like this:

```
replace(replace(replace(body('Create_HTML_table'),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>'),'&quot;','"')
```

[Screen: Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l6fW.jpg)